# How can I find period of the function $\cot(\sqrt{\frac xb})$?

Tags: periodic-functions

How can I find period of the function $\cot(\sqrt{\frac xb})$? I know this is not constant and increases by $x$...

Comment: What makes you think it *has* a period to being with?

Comment: the function is not periodic so...

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not a periodic function so do not try to find its period